# How can I make a random generator in Javascript for a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, random, discord.js, bots

I'm a beginner in coding and I'm trying to learn to code a discord bot that messages a random generated things, like lets say I'm doing an advice command, what I want it to do is to pick 1 out of 10 advice tips randomly. Hopefully anyone understands, thank you.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/zsoltime/discord-dev-jokes-bot

Comment: Hello. Your question is too broad and doesn't focus on a singular issue that you are having issues with. Please provide more details, preferably with examples of code and what you have already tried to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't have a particular issue, my question is making a random generator, I'm wondering on how I can code a random generator, so if someone gives a command to my discord bot, and my bot answers back, by saying the exact same thing, I want to fix that by putting like 10 messages and the random generator picks one of the 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create an array for the randomly generated outcomes.
If we're talking about advice as you mentioned, you would want to type:

```js
const advices = [
  'eat melon',
  'eat melon every day',
  'eat melon a lot',
  'melon is healthy',
  'melon is very epic'
];
```

Once you've created your array, you can generate a random value from your array by typing:

```js
// get a random number based on the array's length
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * advices.length);
// creates the random output of your array
var randomElement = advices[randomIndex];
```

From there, you can simply use `randomElement` as the randomly generated value from your array.

```js
message.reply(`Here is a good advice: ${randomElement}`);
```